# How to use multiple database in single sql query in single Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, dblink

In below SQL query I am not able to use DBlink using jasper report

*select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'order'
minus 
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'order@DB_test';*

where DB_test is a different server.

Comment: `I am not able to use DBlink` - Did you get some error?

Comment: Yes, I am getting error as : "Error in executing the sql statement is dbms active?" also I am using ireport tool to generate the jasper report

Comment: Did you check query with another client from the same pc?

Comment: yes it is working fine, I went through the online info and found to use different database in one single query using ireport  we need to use subreports. but I dont have idea how to use subreport using ireport. Could you please help for the above sql query, basically I need to find column mismatch between two table. and both the table is on different  database server.